# Use C# to create html

Tags: c#, .net

Working on a scrolling picture slider and need to dynamically create hyperlinks and divs in a specific div on the page so that I can then control it with JQuery.

```
<div id="scroller"><!-- here is where I want the html to be created and what needs to be created --><a href="#" class="scrollimage"><img src="images/image10.jpg"/> </a></div>
```

I have created an array that gathers the number of files in the directory and can loop the number of times to add the files but not sure how to place the html in the specific div.

Comment: Are you actually working on an ASP.NET website here? Or do you literally have an HTML page and some Javascript code and are looking to get started on writing some server-side code for the first time?

Comment: It's an asp.net website and within the masterpage there I am creating an image scroller. I have the page built, I have the image scroller / JQuery working but need to dynamically add hyperlinks and images which is contained in a directory on the web sites server. For each image I need to add within the <div id="scroller"> </div> a hyperlink tag and an image tag. This is not my first time writting server-side code but I'm just not trained in how things releate and the optimal language to use for different scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you don't want to use C# to generate HTML.

Since your using .NET, I'm assuming that your using either ASP.NET Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC.

In the case of Web Forms, you should use a server control like the Repeater and databind to your array of files.

In the case of MVC, return the data as either your View Model or part of it.

If you're dead set on generating HTML in C#, take a look at [Html32TextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.html32textwriter.aspx)

EDIT: Here's a way to do it in ASP.NET WebForms. Note that this isn't a complete example, it's just enough to get you on **a** right track.

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    scrollerRepeater.ItemDataBound += BindScrollerItem;

    var files = Directory.GetFiles("*.jpg").Select(filename=>new FileInfo(filename));
    scrollerRepeater.DataSource = files;
    scrollerRepeater.DataBind();
}

private void BindScrollerItem(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    ListItemType type = e.Item.ItemType;
    if(type != ListItemType.Item && type!=ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        return;
    }

    var file = e.Item.DataItem as FileInfo;
    if(file == null)
        return;

    var image = e.Item.FindControl("scrollerImage") as HtmlImage;
    if (image == null)
        return;

    image.Src = 
}
```

ASPX

```
<div id="scroller">
<!-- here is where I want the html to be created and what needs to be created 
<a href="#" class="scrollimage"><img src="images/image10.jpg"/> </a>
-->
<asp:Repeater ID="scrollerRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="#" class="scrollimage"><img alt="" runat="server" id="scrollerImage"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Comment: In my case then what is the best practice to determine the number of images in a directory on the server and then place them into a specific div <div id="scroll"></div> wrapped by a hyperlink tag? If this isn't C# is it java? or another language? In the end I am using Jquery to apply movement action to the images.

Comment: There's a handful of ways to skin that cat, Roll12. Can you give us some more info about your environment? We know you're using C# on the server. Are you using ASP.NET web forms?

Comment: It's built into an asp.net page .aspx and actually is part of the masterpage. It not a form that people input information to but a section of the page that loads images from the image directory and then becomes interactive with JQuery. Problem is I need it to go to the directory and see how many images are in there and then create html so I can get the JQuery to animate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **XSL** I made some reports in HTML with XSL, here an [example](https://web.archive.org/web/20100228132114/http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=63)